# Bematech MP 4200 TH - dll MP2032 saber se finalizou a impressão

Tags: c#, .net

Boa Tarde, estou desenvolvendo uma integração com pagamento via TEF da getnet em c#, meu problema esta na impressão do cupom de confirmação de pagamento, e para homologação eu preciso ter certeza se a impressão finalizou ou não.

Estou usando a dll MP2032, disponibilizado pela bematech, eu pesquisei e vi que existe o metodo EsperaImpressao eu passo 1 e o retorno é 1 , o codigo continua sem esperar o final da impressão.

Por que se nao finalizar a impressão eu preciso cancelar a operação.

Alguem consegue me ajudar??

Obrigado

Comment: voce tem a documentacao da biblioteca ?

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, cara so consegui encontrar uma classe e tem documentacao na classe, e diz que espera a finalizacao da impressao mas de fato isso nao acontece.

Comment: O método é assíncrono? Onde está o seu código?

Answer (score -1):

opa beleza... cara tenta isso aqui

```
MP2032.HabilitaEsperaImpressao(1); //isso vai habilitar o modo de espera

MP2032.EsperaImpressao(1);//e isso aqui é para que a função aguarde a finalização da impressão
```